# How to connect mysql with eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, ide

How can i connect mysql db with eclipse, can someone please help me.what version of eclipse,JRE i need and how to fetch or what IDE is easy to connect mysql such as netbeans or pycharm if python is easy.

Comment: IDE is for writing code. Do you want to write a java program that connects to MySQL? Or are you looking for a database client, i.e. a program you run that allows you to run SQL queries?

Comment: Hi manoj, thanks for ur response.. actually i need to connect mysql db with IDE either java or python. Apparently i need to get a user input and store it in a variable and I'll pass that variable into sql code's where condition

Answer (score 3):

**Which version?** 
You can use any version. But the [latest](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) is always better.

**Which JRE?** 
If you are developing applications using Java you need to install JDK. It will install the JRE. And you need to add JDK bin path to your System Variables. And [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java) and [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) are examples that showing how to do that.

**How to setting up JDBC Connection,** 
First, you need to download the [MySQL Connector for Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.16).

And setting up a JDBC connection in Eclipse is much easier. You can try this,

Right-click on your Java Project in the Package Explorer in the Eclipse workspace and go to Properties
Go down the list that appears until you find `Java Build Path` and click `Libraries` and then click `Add External Archives`.
Find the downloaded jar file called `mysql-connector-java-version number.jar` and choose it. This should import your jar file to Eclipse!

**Finally,** 
And now you can code. Sample Java JDBC Connection,

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

class MySQLConnection {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/some_db";
    String username = "some_username":
    String password = "some_password";

    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

      System.out.println("Connected!");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new Error("Error ", ex);
    } finally {
      try {
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AbrahamVensaslas You are welcome :) And if this answer is helpful you can accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need java mysql connector jar and add it to java build path.
Refer this : https://ibytecode.com/blog/jdbc-mysql-connection-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can either use eclipse neon or eclipse IDE for Java Developers.Then you have to attach Mysql connection drivers to your program.Then you can write this code in your program.

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");

test is your db name you can write yours